# MySQL get one more result out of time range

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm making a PHP based site designed to display line graphs based on data over time. Where the user selects a time range and gets a graph corresponding to what was selected.

The problem is that to calculate any given point, I need to know the previous record. I have no way of knowing when it was, it may have been an hour or a week before hand, but it could have been a minute.

So is there anyway, from within SQL, to specify a time range and one record before that?

Comment: Show us some sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do another query that gets the last record before the time range:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE time < @start_time
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

You can combine this with the original query using `UNION`.